# Javascript - manipulating and using this variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying use this function that changes the class and onclick of another element.

```
partner = this.id + 'Content';

            document.getElementById(partner).className = 'newswrapper';
            document.getElementById(partner).onclick = function(){ clickNews(this); } ;
```

the id of the element with the onclick looks like this.

```
echo'<div id="newsSlide'.$counter.'" class="newsimage" 
            onclick="clickNews(this)" 
            style='."'".'background-image:url("../img/'.$row['image'].'")'".'>';
```

and the element that is supposed to have its class changed looks like this

```
echo'<div id="newsSlide'.$counter.'Content" class="newswrapper">';
```

getting the error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

```
echo'<script>';
        echo"function clickNews(id)
        {
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName('newswrapper');
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('newswrapper2');

            var length = y.length,
            element = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
              element = y[i];
              element.className = 'newswrapper2';
            }

            var length = x.length,
            element = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
              element = x[i];
              element.className = 'newswrapper2';
            }

            partner = this.id + 'Content';

            document.getElementById(partner).className = 'newswrapper';
            document.getElementById(partner).onclick = function(){ clickNews(this); } ;

        }";
        echo'</script>';
```

the html can be found
here : http://pastebin.com/6xBNBQwZ
or you can use the HTML inspector **on the actual page here**
here : http://www.uk-sf.com/indextest.php

Answer (score 5):

You're missing `document.`:

```
document.getElementById(partner).className = 'newswrapper';
```

`getElementById` is a method of the document, not the window ;)

Comment: http://www.uk-sf.com/indextest.php Here is where I am testing the function, it isn't working still.

Comment: getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

Comment: All of them work except the last one. This suggests that the last one does not have a corresponding element.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.id` in `partner = this.id + 'Content'` is refer to global variable id on window object not the id to your element, and becouse ther is not global variable the `partner` variable looks like that `undefinedContent`

So change `onclick="clickNews(this.id)"` and than use id from arguments

```
function clickNews(id) 
    {
        partner = id + 'Content'; // use id form arguments
    }
```

And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukaszewczak/WyKDR/3/) with simple example

Comment: solutions? change the onclick to onclick="clickNews(this.id)". And then adapt the function to use the id????????

Comment: sorry could you present me more of a solution, I have been ironing out my PHP ability but I still really am learning with the javascript

Comment: I put a fiddle with simple example